# Parse "-30.00" to a float results in -3000.0

Tags: c#, parsing, digits

Whenever I try to parse the String

"-30.00" to a float, I'll get -3000.0 as a result.

Can someone explain to me why that happens? What can I do to avoid such a problem?

Here's the code:

Note: `splitMin` is `"MIN(-30.00)"` and `splitMax` is `"MAX(70.00)"` in the beginning. This is why I had to remove a few characters.

```
splitMin = splitMin.Remove(0, 4);
splitMax = splitMax.Remove(0, 4);

splitMin = splitMin.Remove(splitMin.Length - 1, 1);
splitMax = splitMax.Remove(splitMax.Length - 1, 1);

float min = float.Parse(splitMin);
float max = float.Parse(splitMax);
```

Comment: Could you show the code ?

Comment: Sure but I don't think It will make much difference. I'll edit it in a sec...
Thanks for the fast answer btw.

Comment: specifically, what are you trying to remove from the first 4 line of code?

Comment: put a break point immediately after the code you have shown here and check the values, there is no reason for it to get -3000 unless you multiply by 100, or what culture are you using?

Comment: As I mentioned SplitMin is "MIN(-30.00)" in the beginning. I'm removing the "MIN(" in the first line and the ")" in the second part, this way all I have left is the number which I'll need.

Comment: As Sayse said : which culture do you use ? Maybe the . stands for hundred's separetor

Comment: try to debug after you parse, its probably somewhere where you are displaying it to the gui. Your code is actually correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just checked with

```
Console.WriteLine(float.Parse("30,00"));
```

And this does return 3000 for me, so I'd imagine your culture settings are in play here.

Try

```
float.Parse(splitMin, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Note: `float.TryParse` would be an improvement

Comment: Great!
Work's like a charm now.
Thanks a lot.